# Type checking in compilers

Tags: compiler-construction, typechecking

I'm currently trying to create a TypeChecker that will successfully type check a MiniJava program.  I've been working on it, staring at it, for the past 10 hours, but I have no idea even where to begin.  I have given up getting the project done in time, but I want to still learn how it's done.  We are given complete parser for MiniJava and a set of classes used for traversing the Abstract Syntax Tree as well as two different default Visitors, DepthFirstVisitor and GJDepthFirst. We are supposed to extend these visitors to get the project done.

I understand the VERY basic concept of what needs to get done: we need to catch errors in the code that the parser couldn't catch.  We need to run through the code in 2 passes.  The first pass is building the symbol table (?) and the 2nd, to use the symbol table to check.  Is this correct?
But then I have no idea where or how to begin to implement this in code.

I realize this isn't really a question.......but any kind of guidance or help will be greatly appreciated.  I have a few friends in my class who are in the exact same boat as me.

Thank you!

Comment: It's basically a traversal of the AST but it's too big a topic for a question here. Surely you must have already been educated as to how this is done?

Comment: We are trying to educate ourselves now :(  But I understand what you mean by traversing the AST.  I know what an AST is, but the code implementation...we have no idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have any idea about your code implementation either. It's pretty hard to help without knowing what you're starting with.

Comment: As @EJP said it's a tree traversal. On the first traversal you build the symbol table--you can think of it as a dictionary--by looking at all the tree nodes that introduce new identifiers--e.g. field definitions, local variables. In the symbol table you remember the type associated with the identifier, its scope, and other info that you might need later. On the second pass, using the symbol table and some rules--e.g. adding two ints will give you an int--you can check if your program is well typed. This is just rough description.

Comment: @Alex, you do not need two passes (and if `auto` is present, you *cannot* have two passes). Any arbitrarily complex type system can be handled in one pass - first you annotate all the expressions with *type variables*, then you generate a set of *equations* using simple rules for each expression and statement node. And then solve the equations separately (e.g., using a Prolog-like engine).

Comment: @SK-logic I know that type checking (and inference for that matter) algorithms work in one pass, but the OP said that his homework required two passes so I presented it like that.

Comment: @Alex, I see, have not noticed that. This requirement excludes `auto` then, good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your language is Java-like, you can do a simple type propagation instead of a more generic type inference. First, you have to define a new AST, with each expression annotated with its type. Then, perform a depth-first (for expressions) / breadth-first (for block statements) transform from your old AST into the new one, applying simple rules for each node:

- Every variable is annotated by its type, and since you've been going breadth-first over your blocks you must have all the variable types fixed by the moment a variable is referenced. This applies to class fields, method arguments and locally scoped variables.
- Every literal yields a default type (string is a string, integer number is, say, a 32bit integer, floating point number is double, etc.)
- Binary arithmetic operations would insert implicit casts based on some ranking rules (pick up any, it does not really matter)
- Ternary operator checks if first argument is boolean and two other arguments are of the same type
- A method call is the most complicated thing here: you have to get the first possible overloaded method with argument types to which you can cast all your arguments implicitly. It's up to you what to do if there are conflicts.
- and so on...

Statements cannot be annotated with types, but you'll have to check their expression arguments types and possibly do implicit casting. Also you can infer `var` or `auto` types at this stage  (please note, it is not a "type inference", just a special case of type propagation).